# Uncaught TypeError: _react.default.createContext is not a function. I have latest version of react and react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, createcontext

I am trying to upgrade the application and using following versions for react and react-redux but getting this error."Uncaught TypeError:_react.default.createContext is not a function". The solution I have found so far is asking to update react and react-redux but it's already updated.
React : ^17.0.1,
React-dom : ^ 17.0.1,
React-redux : ^7.2.2,
React-router: ^ 5.2.0

Comment: What is your code?